# MongoDB connectivity with PHP dropping after idle time

Tags: php, mongodb, database-connectivity, database

I'm building a webapp with MongoDB/PHP, and everything's going great... except one thing.

My database connection is flaky. After X amount of time, when I refresh the page I get errors because queries are failing. I check mongod.exe and what I see is "Connection accepted from 127.0.0.1" - then I go back, refresh again, and everything's running all well and good.

What could be causing this? Database connectivity issues are something I never had to deal with in MySQL - but that's a whole different beast.

Comment: What OS are you running on?  How are you connecting to mongo from php?

Comment: I'm on Windows 7 64 bit. Connecting like so now:
`try{
   $this->db = new Mongo();
  }catch(MongoConnectionException $e){
   die('Mongo could not connect.');
  }` Before it was just `$this->db = new Mongo();`

Comment: Is it "couldn't send query: No error" error ? If yes, please check here ( https://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/71aa93e01dfd7f65/a67fae24cbe4cc1c ) . And check you have last updated driver.

Comment: I received this again today, and I did a little more research. As far as I can see, a lot of Mongo users are getting this. My extension was more current than the one on Mongo's Github, somehow, so I looked elsewhere for newer versions. I downloaded from the php.net page "PHP 5.3 VC9 Thread-Safe Mongo extension," which is more current than the github and my former installation. I'm hoping this solves it. I'll keep this thread updated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly recommend you do your development with mongodb in a unix environment as they update the code the most often and you won't have to worry about strange bugs. Long ago i decided that doing dev in windows was much too inconvenient and moved my work environment to linux. If this sounds daunting, you might look into running a virtual machine with a local mount via samba such that you can run directly on a linux server on your local machine. Then you will have an environment similar to your production env. Hope this is helpful.